# Python youtube-dl It is possible to get merging file's extension?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

When I run it:

```
ydl_opts = {
    'outtmpl': files_path + '%(id)s.%(ext)s',
}
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            ydl.download([video_url])
```

I get it in logs:

```
[ffmpeg] Merging formats into "/home/tmp/0uBOtQOO70Y.mkv"
[wsgi:error] Deleting original file /home/tmp/0uBOtQOO70Y.f137.mp4 (pass -k to keep)
[wsgi:error] Deleting original file /home/tmp/0uBOtQOO70Y.f251.webm (pass -k to keep)
```

How can I get **/home/tmp/0uBOtQOO70Y.mkv** before or after download?

If I make it:

```
ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
     info = ydl.extract_info(video_url, download=False)
```

Then in **info** was **mp4** extension

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, from what I can tell youtube-dl doesn't return extension of the output file. The extension from `ydl.extract_info()` is useless if formats are merged into another format. You can check if formats will be merged by `ydl.extract_info()['format_id']` – if there is "+" symbol between numbers, they will be merged. However we still can't tell what the output format will be.
I created a clumsy workaround for this. Since we can control the name of the output file (without an extension, which is very hard to predict) I just checked if files with most probable extensions exits.

```
url = 'https://linktovideofile.com/'
filename = './example'
ytdl_opts = {'outtmpl': filename+'.%(ext)s'}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_opts) as ytdl:
    ytdl.download([url])

if os.path.isfile(filename+'.mkv'):
    extension = '.mkv'
    filename= filename+extension
elif os.path.isfile(filename+'.mp4'):
    extension = '.mp4'
    filename= filename+extension
elif os.path.isfile(filename+'.webm'):
    extension = '.webm'
    filename= filename+extension
```

I hope this helps, it works for my simple script but may be insufficient for more advanced one.